# Pandas: How to add number of the row within grouped rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

so I have DataFrame:

```
>>> df2
      text
0  0  a  
0  1  b
0  2  c
0  3  d
1  4  e
1  5  f  
1  6  g  
2  7  h  
2  8  1
```

How do I create another column, which contains counter for each row within an level=0 index?

I have tried the following code (i need to get df['counter'] column):

```
current_index = ''
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  if index[0] != current_index:
    current_index = index[0]
    df[(df.index == current_index)]['counter'] = np.arange(len(df[(df.index == current_index)].index))
```

and following code as well:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for group, df in df1.groupby('level_0_column'):
  df0 = df0.sort_values(by=['level_1_column'])
  df['counter'] = list(df.reset_index().index.values + 1)
  df2 = df2.append(df0)
```

I have around 650K rows in DataFrame... goes to infinite loop. Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `groupby` along the 0<sup>th</sup> column index + `cumcount`:

```
df['counter'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1
df

    text  counter
0 0    a        1
  1    b        2
  2    c        3
  3    d        4
1 4    e        1
  5    f        2
  6    g        3
2 7    h        1
  8    1        2
```

Comment: Maybe `df['counter'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1` to count starting with one instead of zero.